# QGIS 1.8 python refresh maps

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

i have developed this plugin .. everything works fine but the map wont get refreshed . here is the code:

```
    vectorCount =0
mpointCount=0
mlineCount=0
mpolygonCount=0
mrasterCount=0
mlegnd = self.iface.legendInterface()
# add the groups and save their index in variable 
# self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
legnd.addGroup('0_Points')
legnd.addGroup('1_Lines')
legnd.addGroup('2_Polygons')
legnd.addGroup('3_Rasters')
mw = self.iface.mainWindow()
lgd = mw.findChild(QTreeWidget, "theMapLegend")  # get ref to object by type/objectName
lgd.sortItems(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)  # sort first column (Qt.DescendingOrder to reverse)
for layer in legnd.layers():
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        # layer.setCacheImage( None )
        # layer.triggerRepaint()
        vectorCount=vectorCount+1
        QRect=layer.extent().toString()
        f = QgsFeature()
        f.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromRect( layer.extent()) )
        area=f.geometry().area()    
        #QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", " Layer extent area %s "%(area) )
        if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point:
            pointCount=pointCount+1
            legnd.moveLayer(layer, 0)
        elif layer.geometryType() == QGis.Line:
            lineCount=lineCount+1
            legnd.moveLayer(layer, 1)
        elif layer.geometryType() == QGis.Polygon:
            polygonCount=polygonCount+1
            legnd.moveLayer(layer, 2)
        else:
            QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", " Sorry, This version of plugin supports limited data formats " )
    elif layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
        rasterCount=rasterCount+1
        legnd.moveLayer(layer, 3)
    else:
            QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", " Sorry, This version of plugin supports limited data formats " )
```

i tried all this but it won't work ... any suggestions? what i am doing wrong ?

```
    self.iface.setVisible(True);
    self.iface.refresh() 
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
layer.setCacheImage( None )
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the map canvas object.

```
self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Comment: nope it not working i tried

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sort the legend into groups?

Comment: adding groups to the legend then sorting/transferring  layers in to respective groups ..

Comment: I want to access and change the layer number/sequence directly is it possible without groups  ?

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem. It ended by adding the following at the beginning of my code. Among all the imports needed, there was one I forgot:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
```

hope it helps.